# How does music streaming services like pandora or spotify store files offline in ios

Tags: ios, streaming, offline

Am building a streaming app like pandora or spotify. I have completed the android version. The problem is with iOS. Apple does not allow for the songs to be downloaded onto the phone. They keep rejecting the binary. So my question is how does apps like spotify or pandora manage to have songs stored for offline playback in iOS.
I just need pointers in the right direction.
If i know how they do it, i can do it too.

Comment: I am not sure but. You can download file into local with specific identifier and load from there if available other wise start streaming  and download in background

Comment: Thanks for your comment!Am able to stream and download in background. it plays well. But am not able to get it past app review. Apparently apple does not allow audio file download. So how is spotify able to save songs to playing offline.

Comment: Any Solution ?.

Answer (score 0):

where do you store your downloaded files? and did Apple provide you with, a more detailed information why did they reject the app?

Comment: Regarding the 5.2.3 issue, your app allows users to save or download music, video, or other media content without authorization from the relevant third-party sources.

Please review the Intellectual Property section of the App Store Review Guidelines.

Comment: The files are saved in the phone's local filesystem

Comment: So you don't have any code problems ;) that's good :) but to pass the review you need to comply with the Intelectual Property Regulations which you can find [here](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#intellectual-property) section 5.2. And your app is falling under the point 5.2.3. When you are failing your app for submission there you have this point about *Content Rights* and there you should provide legal information that your app has the permissions to stream/download the content you are providing in your app. Otherwise, your app won't get into the store.

Answer (score 0):

Its been almost a year and i just found a solution for this hurdle. Its memory cache. Instead of using normal download to load the file into the filesystem, a disk cache or memory cache technique is used and that seem to have done the trick. This also improves streaming greatly since files the user has already played is not called from server but called from cache.
There is a small side effect though, you would need to implement a cache manager to prevent writing into cache where disk space is full.